# Getting aspnet_merge error after converting VS 2008 project to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, dll, .net-assembly, aspnet-merge

I am getting an error

```
"aspnet_merge: error 1023: The assemblies cannot be merged because some assemblies have inconsistent attributes: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute. Use -a option to force merge. Use -allowattrs to specify the attributes to skip when checking for consistency."
```

when merging assemblies.

What I have done previous, simply open VS 2008 solution in my VS 2010 without changing .Net Framework (Selected No when VS 2010 prompt me to change .Net Framework to 4.0) and resolve this error `**missing compiler required member System.Runtime. CompilerServices. ExtensionAttribute..ctor**` by changing NewtonSoft dll version from 2.0 to 3.5.

Now after successfully publishing my project, I have to merge dll's but I am getting above error. I have already check in different versions of aspnet_merge (3.5/4.0) but getting the same error.

Please let me know what needs to be done for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It was because the project was not referencing `Microsoft.CSharp`. Once I added a reference to that assembly, it compiled just fine.

If the problem persists, try to reinstall `JSON.Net`.

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version x.x.x.x
```